# How to rename Amazon RDS instance endpoint?

Tags: amazon-ec2, rename, amazon-rds

Say i have an instance with the name of 'webserver' and my endpoint is

```
webserver.i2jfi23dfds.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com
```

The beginning of that string is my instance name.

Can i change the beginning of the endpoint of my instance to something like..

```
adifferentname.i2jfi23dfds.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com
```

Answer (score 3):

This feature was recently added.  Just modify the instance and see you can rename it.

Answer (score 1):

After speaking with them there isn't a way to rename it. I just have to make another copy and rename it.